# Data not inserted into the sqlite table c++

Tags: c++, c, database, sqlite

I am trying to save the contents of the key and value of a map into a database table. The .dbo file is created, but nothing goes into the table. It doesn't create table but it doesn't exit. I wonder what is wrong with my code.

```
void names_table( std::map<std::string, unsigned int> &names ){
std::string sql; 
std::string str1;
std::string str2;
std::string str3;

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *file_names = create_db_file( ); /* default to temp db */
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_initialize( );

int rc = sqlite3_open_v2( file_names, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
if ( rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close( db );
    cout << "Error: Database cannot open!" << endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
}
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names_table (offset INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, stname TEXT);";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), sql.size(), &stmt, NULL);
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Create Table!" << endl;

for (auto pm = names.begin(); pm != names.end(); pm++) {
    str2 = "'" + pm->first + "'";
    char tmp[15];
    sprintf(tmp,"%u",pm->second);
    str3 = tmp;
    str1 = (((("INSERT INTO  names_table VALUES(" + str3) + ", ") + str2) + ");");
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    sql = (char *)str1.c_str();
    // stmt = NULL;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), sql.size(), &stmt, NULL);
    if ( rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        cout << "Error: Data cannot be inserted!" << endl;
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
sqlite3_close( db );
```

}

Comment: `exit(-1)` is not recommended (at least in C)

Comment: Thank you David. what do you recommend for error handling?

Comment: Most likely, you have some errors in your SQL syntax. Try to `std::cout << str1 << std::endl` and paste it here. Also, what is the return value for the second call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`?

Comment: @Persianux `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`

Comment: I cout one of the statements for str1: INSERT INTO names_table VALUES(ramsar, 8329); the return value for rc is 0

Comment: @Persianux I wasn't asking for the value of `rc`. Try changing your code inside the `for` loop to catch the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and see if it's different than `SQLITE_OK` (which translates to 0).

Comment: @Mihai that's right it exits at second sqlite3_prepare_v2

Comment: As a side note, your script will probably die if the `names_table` table already exists in the database file.

Comment: I use Openoffice to see the contents of database file. The file is created, but I can't find any table in it! I guess in INSERT INTO it can't find the table

Comment: @Persianux You're code is just too broken, so I won't bother patching it up line by line. I have added two links in my answer which explain how to create a table and insert data into it properly.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850375/c-create-database-using-sqlite-for-insert-update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT INTO names_table VALUES(ramsar, 8329)` - I hope you're aware that string literals in SQL need to be enclosed in quotes. Try this: `INSERT INTO names_table VALUES('ramsar', 8329)`.

**EDIT:** Actually, your code will never do what you want, because you're not even calling [`sqlite3_step`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) after [`sqlite3_prepare_v2`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), which means that you're only compiling your SQL statement, but never evaluating it. Where did you find this bad example? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10856183/1174378) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451953/1174378) decent examples on how to use the SQLite C++ interface properly.

PS: Stop messing around with `sprintf` in C++. You have `std::stringstream` for it.

Comment: Thank you @Mihai, I was careless. I tried this too, but nothing changed with this correction.

Comment: @Persianux Then see my comment above.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I read the tutorials and write what I understand from them. Your comments helped me so much to know how to work with sqlite. I added sqlite3_step, it can't create table. I try figure out how to fix it. The file is created, though.

Comment: I updated the code. it tuns without error. Created 2kb .odb file. At least the file is not empty, but in Openoffice I can't see any table. The file show this line: SQLite format 3######@  #########################################################################-�

Comment: Although I can't find any table using OpenOffice, it created 13kb .odb file :) It stored data I wanted. Thank you, I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you use something smarter to query that database? You can either do it with the native sqlite application via command line or with the Firefox plugin [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). Perhaps Open Office is messing with you.

Comment: Also, in your updated code, you're still not calling `sqlite3_step` after the last `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. That code will just create one empty database table, without inserting any data into it...